# Data is not being updated (always getting the same result) after the project is deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, vercel

I created an api endpoint in my Next.js `v13.2` application that fetches data from a database.

```
app/api/someData
```

This was working well until I deployed it on Vercel. I think the problem is that the route is being cached and, as a result, returns the same response every time. How do I stop this from occurring?

I am using the new `app` directory in Next.js that uses [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because in the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) directory and on production, Next.js by default caches all fetched data in API Routes and Server Components. If you are using [`fetch()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), you can change this behavior per query, with `revalidate` or `cache` option:

```js
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 10 } });
// OR
fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' });
```

If you are using [`fetch()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch) but want to set the cache per route segment, or you're using another library like `axios`, or talking directly to your database with an ORM, you can use [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config):

```js
// layout.js OR page.js OR route.js 

import prisma from "./lib/prisma";

/*
  Bleow option is when you want no caching at all, there are more options
  on the doc depending on your needs. 
*/
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

async function getPosts() {
  const posts = await prisma.post.findMany();
  return posts;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting same data when opening API route directly with url, you can put the following setting on the end of api/xx/route.js to skip the cache and revalidate the data.

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```