# How to use NEXTJ13 data fetch axios

Tags: next.js

```js
fetch('https://...', { cache: 'no-store' });

fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 10 } });

fetch('https://...'); // cache: 'force-cache' is the default
```

In the official documentation, it says that the above method fetches data using server-side -renering, but how do I use it with axios?
Does nextjs recommend fetch over axios?

Comment: You can use axios or whatever you want, as usual. The only thing is that there is a caching behavior introduced by Next.js that's tied to `fetch` currently. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/how-to-avoid-caching-for-a-next-js-api-route-using-the-app-directory/76204625#76204625

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axios library must adapt to next js new fetch methods and axios not support next js cache and revalidate yet.
I suggest you to use fetch because in next 13 all new features are not stable and axios is not a good choice for this case.