# nextjs how to change metada when change context

Tags: next.js, metadata, next.js13

In my project, there is context data related to website languages. When a user changes the website language, the website content also changes accordingly. There is an option called 'i18n' to manage languages, but I haven't used it.

I want to change the metadata when the context data changes. I looked at the Next.js documentation, but I couldn't find anything specific about this.

Is it possible or is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the official page for Metadata?

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata

Also, this post might help you:

[Next JS Dynamic Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76265976/next-js-dynamic-metadata)