# How to immediately update UI after database change in next.js

Tags: next.js, prisma

currently learning next.js and kind of struggling. When the delete text is clicked, it should trigger the toggleDelete function. it successfully deletes the data from the db, but doesn't immediately reflect the changes on the UI. I've tried a couple of things but keep ending up with runtime errors left and right.

How would you go about this? thanks!

```
import { TodoItem } from "@/components/TodoItem";
import { prisma } from "@/db";
import Link from "next/link";

function getTodos() {
  return prisma.todo.findMany();
}

async function toggleTodo(id: string, complete: boolean) {
  "use server";
  await prisma.todo.update({ where: { id }, data: { complete } });
}

async function toggleDelete(id: string) {
  "use server";
  await prisma.todo.delete({ where: { id } });
}

export default async function Home() {
  const todos = await getTodos();

  return (
    <>
      <header className="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">
        <h1 className="text-2xl">Todos</h1>
        <Link
          className="border border-slate-300 text-slate-300 px-2 py-1 rounded hover:bg-slate-700 focus-within:bg-slate-700 outline-none"
          href="/new"
        >
          New
        </Link>
      </header>
      <ul className="px-4">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <TodoItem key={todo.id} {...todo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} toggleDelete={toggleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
"use client";
import { format } from 'date-fns';

type TodoItemProps = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  complete: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
  toggleTodo: (id: string, complete: boolean) => void;
  toggleDelete: (id: string) => void;
};

export function TodoItem({ id, title, complete, createdAt, toggleTodo, toggleDelete }: TodoItemProps) {
  const formattedCreatedAt = format(createdAt, 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a');

  return (
    <li className="flex justify-between items-center">
      {/* option to cross it out */}
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <input
          id={id}
          type="checkbox"
          className="cursor-pointer peer"
          defaultChecked={complete}
          onChange={(e) => toggleTodo(id, e.target.checked)}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor={id}
          className="cursor-pointer ml-2 peer-checked:line-through peer-checked:text-slate-500"
        >
          {title}
        </label>
      </div>
      {/* when was it made */}
      <div className="text-right text-xs">
        Created - {formattedCreatedAt}
      </div>
      {/* delete option */}
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div>
          <p className="text-xs cursor-pointer peer" onClick={() => toggleDelete(id)}>delete</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid caching in the app directory of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/how-to-avoid-caching-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can revalidate the cache within the delete function.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations

```js
// import function to server component 
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'

//call function in your delete method 
async function toggleDelete(id: string) {
   "use server";
   await prisma.todo.delete({ where: { id } });
   revalidatePath('/')
}
```