# NextJS 13 w/ MongoDB - Data won't update in real time in production, but works on dev

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, vercel

I have a problem that I find hard to diagnose.

I'm trying to build a CRUD app using **NextJS, mongoose and MongoDB**. Everything works great, but **the data does not automatically modify itself on the deployment website on Vercel**, after I am changing it inside MongoDB. **Howver, locally, on localhost:3000, the data does change automatically after mongoDB models are being changed**.

1. The first thing I did was create a utils folder at the root of the project. Inside of it, I have created a file called **db.js**, which looks like this:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectMongoDB = () => {
  try {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
    console.log('connected to MONGODB');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err:', err);
  }
};

export default connectMongoDB;
```

2. I have then created a route inside the api folder, and in the **route.js**, I have the following code:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import connectMongoDB from '../../../../utils/db';
import PachetAnimatori from '../../../../models/pachetAnimatori';

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    connectMongoDB();
    const pacheteAnimatori = await PachetAnimatori.find();
    return NextResponse.json(pacheteAnimatori);
  } catch (err) {
    return new NextResponse('Error when getting pacheteAnimatori', { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

3. Finally inside my **page.tsx** file inside the matching route, I'm extracting the data and displaying it. The file looks like this:

```js
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import header from '../../../assets/chibisuperheroes-header.jpg';
import info from '../../../assets/info-icon.png';
import styles from './page.module.scss';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import PacheteAnimatori from './components/PacheteAnimatori';
import { PachetAnimatori } from '@/types/pachetAnimatori.types';

const getPacheteAnimatori = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_API}/animatori`, { cache: 'no-store' });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('PacheteAnimatori failed to fetch');
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error loading pacheteAnimatori', err);
  }
};

const Animatori = () => {
  const [pachete, setPachete] = useState<PachetAnimatori[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPacheteAnimatori()
      .then((res) => setPachete(res))
      .catch((e) => console.log('e:', e));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.header}>
        <Image
          src={header}
          alt="header"
          className={styles.headerImg}
        />
      </div>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Animatori</h1>
      <div className={styles.paragraphContainer}>
        <p className={styles.description}>
          Prin prezența lor colorată, animatorii au rolul de a transforma total petrecerea copilului
          tău, cu umor și bună dispoziție. Copiii se vor bucura de cele mai distractive provocări,
          jocuri, dansuri, jocuri cu mașina de baloane de săpun, modelajul de baloane, se vor
          transforma în personajele de poveste preferate și vor avea parte de multe alte surprize.
          Uneori, nici măcar părinții nu pot sta pe margine!<br></br>
          Jocurile diferă în funcție de vârstă, de numărul copiilor și de spațiul liber pe care îl
          au la dispoziție pentru a se desfășura în voie. Ne vom adapta în funcție de orice cerință.
          <br></br>
          Suntem echipați cu diverse accesorii (boxe, mașini de baloane, cadouri, jocuri atractive)
          dar mai ales cu multă răbdare, energie și voie bună. Iubim să fim înconjurați de copii. Vă
          puteți baza pe noi pentru ca petrecerea să fie cu totul specială, plină de zâmbete și
          bucurie. Echipa noastră este formată din animatori cu experiență, o echipă tânără, cu
          pregătire în domeniu, actualizând mereu portofoliul de jocuri, coregrafii și dansuri,
          abilitățile de pictură, totul completându-se cu multă energie, distracție și pasiune.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Ofertele noastre</h1>
      <div className={styles.infoWrapper}>
        <Image
          src={info}
          alt="info"
          className={styles.infoIcon}
        />
        <h3 className={styles.infoNote}>
          Vă prezentăm tarifele și serviciile pentru animatori, pachetele noastre și lista
          personajelor disponibile.
        </h3>
      </div>
      <PacheteAnimatori pachete={pachete} />

      <div className={styles.infoWrapper}>
        <Image
          src={info}
          alt="info"
          className={styles.infoIcon}
        />
        <h3 className={styles.infoNote}>
          Pentru a vedea pachetele noastre de servicii complete{' '}
          <Link
            href="/pachete-complete"
            className={styles.serviciiCompleteLink}
          >
            Click aici
          </Link>{' '}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Animatori;
```

After running npm run dev, and going onto the localhost link, everything seems to work great. The data is being displayed, and upon modifying the data inside MongoDB, the data is changing inside my local application.

**The issue arises when deploying to Vercel. I've configured the ENV variables, deployed successfully, and the data is there. However, after I change the data inside MongoDB, the data does NOT change accordingly. It remains like it was initially.**

I don't understand where this issue is coming from, if anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid caching in the app directory of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/how-to-avoid-caching-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the endpoint being cached at build time. NextJS docs mention setting `cache: no-store` at the end of your fetch functions to force revalidating on each request, but this does not work for me.

Anyone else have a good solution or better docs for this spesific stack?

Answer (score 1):

Your GET function might be getting statically optimised.
Try adding export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' from the file.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#caching

I also had that same issue but solved it a day ago.
This is the code example

```
import Prompts from "@/models/Prompt";
import { connectDb } from "@/utils/mongodb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

/**
 * @method GET
 * @returns NextResponse
 * @description Find All Prompts and return
 */
export const GET = async () => {
    await connectDb();

    try {
        const result = await Prompts.find();
        return NextResponse.json(result.reverse(), { status: 200 });
    } catch (err) {
        return NextResponse.json("Failed to get Prompt Template.", {
            status: 500
        });
    }
};
```