# Next 13 client component using SWR not refreshing every reload

Tags: next.js, client-side, next.js13, swr

I'm building a weather app with Nextjs 13 and im rendering the page using "use client" and SWR. When I deploy to vercel the page doesnt fetch the data on reload, instead it acts as a SSR component and builds once.

This is the page at /weather/page.tsx:

```
'use client';

import useSWR, { SWRConfig }  from 'swr';
import { WeatherUI } from '../sections';
import {
  CurrentWeatherProps,
  ForecastProps,
  LocationProps,
} from '../models/Fragments';
import { Loading, Navigation } from '../components';

const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

const WeatherData = () => {
  const { data: rawWeatherData, error } = useSWR(
    '/api/prismaWeather',
    fetcher,
    { refreshInterval: 300000 }
  );

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error fetching data</div>;
  }

  if (!rawWeatherData) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  const weatherDataLocation = rawWeatherData.data[0]
    .location as unknown as LocationProps;
  const weatherDataCurrent = rawWeatherData.data[0]
    .current as unknown as CurrentWeatherProps;
  const weatherDataForecast = rawWeatherData.data[0]
    .forecast as unknown as ForecastProps;

  const weatherData = {
    location: weatherDataLocation,
    current: weatherDataCurrent,
    forecast: weatherDataForecast,
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation
        theme={'black'}
        location={'/weather'}
      />
      <main>
        <WeatherUI weatherData={weatherData} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default WeatherData;
```

What am I missing in this to make it fetch data on every reload? Shouldnt 'use client' do the trick already?

EDIT:

Here is the my API:

```
import prisma from '../../lib/prisma';

export async function GET(req, res) {
  try {
    const rawWeatherData = await prisma.weatherCurrent.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'desc',
      },
      take: 1,
    });

    return Response.json({ data: rawWeatherData });
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({ error: `Error fetching weather data ${error}` });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `/api/prismaWeather/route.js`?

Comment: Sure! just added it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid caching in the app directory of Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/how-to-avoid-caching-in-the-app-directory-of-next-js)

Comment: From what I can understand from that post, the page should be a server component with a revalidation or fetch cache instead of being a server component, solely because I'm using prisma and not a regular fetch function? I will test this suggestion and see if it works! although im still confused as to why the client component is not the way to go for the purpose of the page

Comment: Using a client component is not a problem. You are calling an API route that's sending the same data again because it is cached by Next.js. The lined thread explains how to change the cache behavior.