# Nextjs redirect cause issues at production build

Tags: next.js

User need to login before accessing root dir.
According to this [nextjs doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/authentication#authorization)

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Page() {
  // Logic to determine if a redirect is needed
  const accessDenied = true
  if (accessDenied) {
    redirect('/login')
  }
 
  // Define other routes and logic
}
```

at `app/page.tsx`.

My test shows that at build time if it redirect to another pages, then it will permanent redirecting to that page. Using `next experimental-compile` to skip the prerender state did fix it.

But I am wondering am I doing it wrong? It seems like a generic use case

Asking if it is a bug or just I am doing it wrong

Comment: After posting I found a solution to that adding `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'`. But still I am wondering why everyone else doesn't enconter this problem.

Comment: Hi itsp3! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening cause within the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router, by default, each server component is rendered during build time and cached forever (or until another build occurs).

So if `accessDenied` happens to be true during a build, this page will redirect forever until another build produces a different result.

About this caching, the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#overview) says:

> By default, Next.js will cache as much as possible to improve performance and reduce cost. This means routes are statically rendered and data requests are cached unless you opt out.

So if this redirect logic is to be changed, you need to make the page dynamic, for example with`:

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

A related [post](https://%5Bpost%5D(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76204353/data-is-not-being-updated-always-getting-the-same-result-after-the-project-is)) that might help .

Comment: Yes! 'force-dynamic' did fix my issues. Sorry for the late reply xD