# NextJS SSR Refresh Data without reloading page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

i am trying to render images from the server on a web page.
On the Web Page there is a button to delete a image that refers to an delete request.

Everything is working fine so far.

But the image stays after delete on the page until a reload.

I want the client to remove the image from the page client side without reload.

How do i achieve that?
Dashboard:

```
import { getAllFilesFromFolder } from '../utils/fileUtils';
import ImageCard from "../components/imagecard";
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const path: any = process.env.FOLDER_PATH;
const files = getAllFilesFromFolder(path);

export default function Dashboard() {

    return (
        <main>
            <ToastContainer
                position="top-right"
                autoClose={5000}
                hideProgressBar={false}
                newestOnTop={false}
                closeOnClick
                rtl={false}
                pauseOnFocusLoss
                draggable
                pauseOnHover
                theme="dark"
            />
            <div className="mt-12 mx-20">
                <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-5">
                    {files.map((file, index) => {
                        // Extract file name from the path
                        const fileName = file.split('\\').pop() || file;
                        // Construct the URL with the file name
                        const src = `/api/images/${fileName}`;
                        return <ImageCard key={index} src={src} />;
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </main >
    );
}
```

ImageCard:

```
"use client"
import { ClipboardIcon, TrashIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";
import { Button, Card, Flex, Inset, Tooltip } from "@radix-ui/themes";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import DeleteButtonDialog from "./deletebutton";


interface ImageCardProps {
    src: string;
}

const ImageCard: React.FC<ImageCardProps> = ({ src }) => {
    const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

    const copyLinkToClipboard = () => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.location.host + src)
            .then(() => {
                toast.success('Link erfolgreich kopiert!', {
                    position: "top-right",
                    autoClose: 5000,
                    hideProgressBar: false,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    theme: "dark",
                });
                setCopied(true);
                setTimeout(() => setCopied(false), 2000); // Reset copied state after 2 seconds
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Failed to copy:', error);
            });
    };

    const handleDelete = (confirmed: boolean) => {
        if (confirmed) {
            // Send delete request here
            fetch(src, { method: "DELETE" })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        toast.success('Bild erfolgreich gelöscht!', {
                            position: "top-right",
                            autoClose: 5000,
                            hideProgressBar: false,
                            closeOnClick: true,
                            pauseOnHover: true,
                            draggable: true,
                            progress: undefined,
                            theme: "dark",
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Handle failure
                        console.error("Failed to delete image");
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error while deleting image:", error);
                });
        }
    };


    return (
        <main>
            <Card size="2" style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}>
                <Inset clip="padding-box" side="top" pb="current">
                    <Image
                        src={src}
                        width={1000}
                        height={760}
                        className="hidden md:block"
                        alt="Image Card"
                    />
                </Inset>
                <Flex gap="3">
                    <Tooltip content="Link kopieren">
                        <Button onClick={copyLinkToClipboard} variant="soft">
                            <ClipboardIcon width="16" height="16" />
                        </Button>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <DeleteButtonDialog onDelete={handleDelete}></DeleteButtonDialog>
                </Flex>
            </Card>
        </main >
    );
}

export default ImageCard;
```

Comment: See: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/mutating-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to update a Server Component is to reload the page while making sure the data rendering it is not [cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204625/15288641). As it's sent to the browser as static HTML without any JavaScript attached to it to have interactivity.

To reload the page and still maintain client states, Next.js exposes a [`refresh()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter) method with `next/navigation` that you can call after the API is called:

```
"use client";
// ...

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

// ...

const ImageCard: React.FC<ImageCardProps> = ({ src }) => {
  //...
  const router = useRouter();
  // ....

  const handleDelete = (confirmed: boolean) => {
    if (confirmed) {
      fetch(src, { method: "DELETE" })
        .then((response) => {
          // ...
          router.refresh();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          //...
        })
        
    }
  };
  //...
};

export default ImageCard;
```